# How to work with multiple property files in servicemix

Tags: properties, osgi, placeholder, apache-servicemix

I am using bellow code for place holder 1 property file (under etc folder). It works fine.

```
<osgix:cm-properties id="props" persistent-id="com.order"/>
<ctx:property-placeholder properties-ref="props"></ctx:property-placeholder>
```

Now, if i have multiple property files, how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

you can't. It's one service with one configuration. 
What you can do is have multiple services with those configurations and create a new service that depends on those and gathers these configurations. 
Or if you want to have multiple-configurations for multiple services, take a look at the managed service factory.